# How can i make a java programme run repeatedly

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to run a Java program to display 9 input boxes requesting names and examination scores and display on the message box the names and appropriate grades of each score. I tried doing something like this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class StudentGrade {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputname;
    String inputscore;
    int number;
    inputcourse = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name");
    inputscore = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter score");
    number = Integer.parseInt(inputscore);
    if (number < 40){ 
      System.out.println ((inputcourse) + " " + "D"); }
    else if (number <50){
      System.out.println((inputcourse) + " " + "C");}
    else if (number <60){
      System.out.println((inputcourse) + " " + "B");}
    else System.out.println((inputcourse) + " " + "A");}
 }
```

However, this can only run once. Please, how can I make it run nine times? Thanks.

Comment: See [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) & [The while and do-while Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and notice how they are in the 'nuts an bolts' section of the tutorial  waaaaaay.. before the 'creating a GUI' part of the tutorial?  Take that as a strong hint that you are jumping into making GUIs ***far*** too soon.  They are a lot harder than they might seem.

Answer (score 3):

To loop in control structure you can use a for, while loop, or a do-while loop. For a for-loop you should try:

```
public class StudentGrade{
     public static void main(String[] args){
         for (int i=0; i<9; i++){ repeat 9 times
              // all the code you have in your main method now
         }
     }
}
```

For a while loop you should try:

```
public class StudentGrade{
     public static void main(String[] args){
         int i=0;
         while (i++ < 9){ //repeat 9 times
              // all the code you have in your main method now
         }
     }
}
```

For a do-while loop you should try:

```
public class StudentGrade{
     public static void main(String[] args){
          int i=1;
          do{ //repeat 9 times
             // all the code you have in your main method now
          }while (i++ < 9);
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try this it'll work. In your code Check **Inputname** and **InputCourse** 
or change inputCourse to   inputName

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class world {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputname;
        String inputscore;
        int number;
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            inputname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name");
            inputscore = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter score");
            number = Integer.parseInt(inputscore);
            if (number < 40){ 
               System.out.println ((inputname) + " " + "D");
            }else if (number <50){
               System.out.println((inputname) + " " + "C");
            }else if (number <60){
               System.out.println((inputname) + " " + "B");
            }else {
               System.out.println((inputname) + " " + "A");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put the code inside a for loop:

```
 for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
     inputcourse = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name");
     inputscore = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter score");
     number = Integer.parseInt(inputscore);
     if (number < 40){ 
         System.out.println ((inputcourse) + " " + "D");
     } else if (number <50){
         System.out.println((inputcourse) + " " + "C");
     } else if (number <60){
         System.out.println((inputcourse) + " " + "B");
     } else {
         System.out.println((inputcourse) + " " + "A");
     }
 }
```